# Help with regions in google maps on android phone using Geocoder?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, google-geocoder

I have a search bar in my application for locations, when a user presses the search button i want to search for the address based on the current region the user is in.

At the moment I just call

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(StreetAngelActivity.this,Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(searchBar.getText().toString(),1);
```

But the result is not based on the region the person is in.

How can I ensure that the search retrieves based on the users current location?

I need to somehow find the region the user is in (how would i do this)?

and then append it to the `searchbar.getText()` and pass to the **geocoder**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the link below, you can specify a region. There is no way to specify a region using the Android API, only a locale.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

P.S. You can make a [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) with a custom locale, which is probably your best bet.

Comment: At the moement i am only using geocoder in android library ... i need a way of getting the users region and then appending it to the search

Comment: Take a look at getting the [default locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault())

Comment: Moreover, I should mention that there is no way to pass a region into the default Android GeoCoder, only a locale.

Comment: And locale does not work, i have tried and tested it. How could i ask google api for the current region based on certain co-ords?

Comment: You could get the country they are in from the locale and then map that to a region using the [ccLTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) style.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) article?

Comment: i have the users current location, that is not the problem, just when i use the geocoder, i need to retrieve the region from the current location. how would i do this